# Nginx rewrite index.php?page=contact to just contact

Tags: nginx

I am having trouble with this. I want URL to be rewritten from "index.php?page=somepage" to be written to "somepage".

This is how it was in .htaccess if it helps

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)+\/$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Server block:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name domain.com;

        root /home/www/domain.com;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                rewrite ^/(w+)$ /index.php?page=$1 last;
                rewrite ^/(w+)+/$ /index.php?page=$1 last;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;

        }
}
```

Comment: Provide your whole `server` block please. If looking at the comment to the question below I would suggest something else is going on.

Comment: @JoeDoherty Added the server block to the question.

Comment: don't rewrite, it will still work, try removing the two rewrite commands in php block.

Comment: @Satys I don't want it to be `index.php?page=contact` but rather `contact`

Comment: do you mean /index.php?page=contact to /contact and should it be shown to users, like in browser, or to be done internally?

Comment: @Satys Yes, that's what I want the URL to look like. Internally I want it to take index.php?page=contact and show users /contact

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code,

```
server {
   ...
   rewrite ^/index.php?page=(.*) /$1 permanent;
   ...
   location ~ /(.*) {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?page=$1;
   }

   location ~ \.php {
      ...
      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: It's almost working. I need to get the actual value from the page parameter too. Currently using `$_GET` and I get an empty array.

Comment: Further checking, are you sure the rewrite rule shouldn't be reversed? So that URL's like `/contact` are being processed as `index.php?page=contact` so that the user is actually seeing `/contact`?

Answer (score 0):

Tried using .htaccess to nginx converter and this piece of code seems to work:

```
rewrite ^/(w+)$ /index.php?page=$1 last;
rewrite ^/(w+)+/$ /index.php?page=$1 last;
```

Edit: I overcomplicated things by thinking of rewrites. The solution to what I was trying to do is this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?page=$uri;
}
```